# Hide default site collections from other O365 apps

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, microsoft-teams, office-365-groups

I'm setting up an O365 subscription and I have this setup at the moment:

Sharepoint:
Default Site Collection named: MyCompanyRoot

A MS Teams Team name: MyCompany

If I go to onedrive, I can see in the see in the section Teams and Sites:

- MyCompanyRoot
- MyCompany

Is there a way to hide MyCompanyRoot from all O365 apps and users (even admins) except for SharePoint and admins only?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anyone who holds the SharePoint Admin role, Global Admin role, or Exchange Admin role (possibly others) can see Office 365 Groups. Group Owners and Members can always see the Group.

You can use the Exchange Online cmdlet, [Set-UnifiedGroup](https://docs.microsoft.com/powershell/module/exchange/users-and-groups/set-unifiedgroup?view=exchange-ps) with the `-HiddenFromAddressListsEnabled` and `-HiddenFromExchangeClientsEnabled` to hide the Group from the Global Address List and Outlook desktop and mobile/Outlook on the web clients.

Comment: Thanks, will this command also hide it from onedrive?

Comment: You can't hide it from users who are part of the Group.